# How to debug ssh tunnel that works and then hangs after an indeterminent time

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have two machines, `m_remote` and `m_server`.  I can successfully set up an ssh tunnel from `m_remote` to `m_server` using:

```
ssh -f -N -T -R22222:localhost:22 m_remote_user_on_server@123.123.123.123 -i /path/to/.ssh/m_remote_key
```

Where `123.123.123.123` is the `m_server` IP address.  And I can successfully use that tunnel from `m_server` to `m_remote` using:

```
ssh m_server_user_on_remote@localhost -p 22222 -i /path/to/.ssh/m_server_key
```

However after a period of time the tunnel becomes unresponsive and it's no longer possible to use it.  I have to access the remote machine directly and restart the tunnel.  Is there any way of debugging this?  From the remote all I get is:

```
$ ssh -vvvv m_server_user_on_remote@localhost -p 22222 -i /home/server_user/.ssh/m_server_key
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/server_user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /home/server_user/.ssh/m_server_key type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/server_user/.ssh/m_server_key-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
```

Then after a long pause of at least 2 minutes it logs out:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Though this is due to a cron job I've set up to periodically kill and restart the tunnel.

** **Edit** **

On OSX 10.11 it's the same debug log with an additional line:

```
...
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501   # <-- additional line before hanging
```

Comment: The two close votes are for this being off topic for stack overflow.  But there are similar questions asked, there's also an `ssh-tunnel` tag, finally the help centre states: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", - the only reason I'm here is that I'm trying to use a tool namely `ssh-tunnel` to deploy and update software and currently I can't.  If you think it should be migrated please say so rather than just voting to close it without leaving a comment which is frustrating.  Thank you.

Comment: I assume this falls under the rather critical ["Don't migrate crap"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/195335), if you could help me improve it in any way so that it could be migrated that would be gratefully appreciated.  I have struggled with this for a few hours and have turned to stackoverflow for help as I can't make any more progress myself.  Thank you.

Comment: You should consider asking this on [su] or [unix.se]. When you do, you should include a more complete debug trace. The trace that you posted cuts off pretty early in the ssh protocol startup. Either you didn't include the whole thing, or the fact that it stops there is part of your problem.

Comment: Thanks very much @Kenster  Yes it just stops there and hangs for more than a minute, that's the full log.  I will rerun and wait for longer to see if it eventually times out and then repost onto one of the others as you recommended.

Comment: For negative votes please leave a comment to explain so that the question and questioner can improve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain as I need to diagnose and correlate this but as the m_remote machine is on a flaky home wifi connection this may be dropping and causing the tunnel to hang.

Alternatively there may be some config option such as `ControlPersist` (which may only be relevant to master connections) which has a low default of perhaps 10 minutes which could be increased.